# Editing the same information from multiple pages

Tags: information-architecture

I am having some trouble figuring out the best experience here. Let's say you have separate user and team pages, contextually it makes sense in those pages to show the users you have in your team and vice-versa.

Here's a basic example:

[image: Team and User Table]

So in this example, you could potentially remove users from the teams in the first table, or remove the team from the user from the second one.

While this might not be a terrible experience it gets even more confusing if you have a team details page that lists each member out individually, or a user details page that has each team individually.

Additionally there could be other things on these pages that make sense contextually but possibly should not be edited on these pages. For example, organization permissions or account activity.

How do you handle cyclical information? Is it best to have one centralized place to edit each thing and have read-only information on the other pages, or should you enable the user to edit the information anywhere in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to enable edit in only single location. This is taken care of at the back. Once you update your record, it will be saved at the back. This updated record will be reflected everywhere the same because it comes from the same source. From the client (user) side, if you only reload the page, the new data should be displayed as saved last.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the last couple of examples (organization permissions or account activity) since I don't know what those look like or do, but I would say it would be a better experience if what you update in one place took effect throughout the whole site/app.

If you remove a user from a team on the Teams view, then that team should no longer be listed for that user if you're in the Users view. It would be confusing if it didn't properly update everywhere.